# При изменении select появляется <p> элемент и input

Tags: javascript, html, select, input

Есть select с видами связи

```
<form id="form">
<select name="liason" id="liason" onchange="comFunction();">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="skype">Skype</option>
        <option value="vk">Вконтакте</option>
        <option value="icq">ICQ</option>
        <option value="facebook">Facebook</option>
</select>   
</form>
```

И функция которая должна создавать элементы `input` и `p`

```
function comFunction() {
    var tempSelectLiason = document.getElementById('liason');
    var tempOptionLiason = tempSelectLiason.options[tempSelectLiason.selectedIndex].value;
    if (tempSelectLiason == 'Skype') {
        var skype = document.createElement('P');
        var temp = document.createTextNode('Введите свой скайп');
        var input = document.createElement('input');

        skype.appendChild(temp);
        form.appendChild(skype);
        form.appendChild(input);
    }
}
```

Что не так с функцией, и правильный ли это подход к данного рода задаче?

Comment: Что не так с функцией: if (tempOptionLiason == 'skype') { Что такое `form`?

Comment: Хорошо бы понять, какой результат вы хотите получить в итоге. При выборе какого-либо пункта, создавать соответствующее ему сообщени и, input с определенным именем или что?

Comment: Да, хочу чтобы при выборе option в select появлялась форма для ввода input а над ним параграф например: "Введите скайп" , если в select я выбрал Skype, или "Введите email", если я выбрал email

Comment: form это id формы в которой этот select находится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 var mes = {
   skype: function() {
     var skype = document.createElement("P");
     var temp = document.createTextNode("Введите свой скайп");
     var input = document.createElement("input");
     skype.appendChild(temp);
     form.appendChild(skype);
     form.appendChild(input)
   },
   vk: function() {
     alert("vk")
   },
   icq: function() {
     alert("icq")
   },
   facebook: function() {
     alert("facebook")
   }
 }

 function comFunction(sel) {
   if (mes[sel.value]) {
     mes[sel.value]();
     mes[sel.value] = null;
   }
   sel.value = "";
 }
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <select name="liason" id="liason" onchange="comFunction(this);">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="skype">Skype</option>
    <option value="vk">Вконтакте</option>
    <option value="icq">ICQ</option>
    <option value="facebook">Facebook</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает.
Будет ли лучше если я применю switch case в случае если у меня будет много видов связи.
И как сделать чтобы при втором нажатии (например Skype) не появлялся второй такой же input?

Comment: @WiAim посмотрите отредактированный вариант ответа выше

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var d = document,
  output = d.querySelector('output'),
  titles = {
    skype: 'Введите свой скайп',
    vk: 'Введите свой nickname в Вконтакте',
    icq: 'Введите номер ICQ',
    facebook: 'Введите свой nickname в Facebook'
  };
liason.addEventListener('change', function() {
  output.innerHTML = titles.hasOwnProperty(this.value) ? '<p>' + titles[this.value] + '</p><input name="' + this.value + '">' : '';
}, false);
```

```html
<select name="liason" id="liason">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="skype">Skype</option>
  <option value="vk">Вконтакте</option>
  <option value="icq">ICQ</option>
  <option value="facebook">Facebook</option>
</select>
<output></output>
```

Comment: А не могли бы объяснить пожалуйста? Крайнюю строку не могу понять?

Comment: @WiAim, если в объекте есть соответствующее свойство, то выводим элементы, подставляя в `<p>` значение этого свойства и в атрибут `name` элемента `input` - значение ключа (*если нужно*). В противном случае - выводим пустую строку, заменяя/"очищаяя" тем самым контент в `<output>`